# Create a key in a nested dict without using update function

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Input :

```
{'Name': 'A','Blood Group': 'O +ve', 'Age': '1', 'Sex': 'M','Phone  Number': '01234567', 'Mobile Number': '9876543210', 'Date of Birth': '01-01-95'}
```

1.

```
 d.update({'Contact Info': {'Mobile Number':d['Mobile Number'],'Phone 
                 Number':d['Phone Number'] }})
```

2.

```
d['Contact Info']={}
d['Contact Info']['Mobile Number']=d['Mobile Number']
```

Can you say any better way or different way to create a dictionary key which can be assigned to a dict item as value???

Original Code:

```
import csv
import copy
from collections import namedtuple

d={}
ls=[]

def nest():
    with open ("details.csv", 'r') as f:
        reader=csv.DictReader(f)

        for row in reader:

            d.update(row)
            PersonalDetails = namedtuple('PersonalDetails','blood_group age sex')
            ContactInfo = namedtuple('ContactInfo','phone_number mobile_number')

            d1=copy.deepcopy(d)
            ls.append(d1)
        print ls

nest()
```

Comment: `setdefault()`. What do I win?

Comment: If you can explain it with an example for my case, I can accept your answer, as I'm a newbie

Comment: I would have but it is not very clear to me what you are doing here. Are you trying to modify a dictionary in place using itself somehow? or nest an existing dictionary inside a bigger one? Like a babushka for your anushka?

Comment: I have read a csv file with details of name,age,mob no, phone no, date of birth, sex. I'm trying to create a nested dict of contact info where mob no, phone town keys and their values are updated to the dict

Comment: Then how about the `csv` module with its `DictReader`?

Comment: Thats done. I just want to update keys and values of mobile number and phone number to a new key named contact info which would be in the format of nested dict. Dont know how and whether to use setdefault or defaultdict to create a nested dict.

Comment: I have edited my original codes. When i run it, i dont get nested dict of personal details and contact info

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would update my dict of dicts:

I would create a function that will take a 3 arguments(The key of the subdict, the subkey of said subdict and the value you want to change.) I assign to be updated and then update that value.

```
d = {
    'Name': 'A',
    'Personal Details': {'Blood Group': 'O +ve', 'Age': '1', 'Sex': 'M'},
    'Contact Info': {'Phone  Number': '01234567', 'Mobile Number': '9876543210'},
    'Date of Birth': '01-01-95'
    }


def updateInfo(toBeUpdated, subkey, ValueToUpdate):
    if toBeUpdated in d:
        tempdict = d[toBeUpdated]
        tempdict[subkey] = ValueToUpdate
        d[toBeUpdated] = tempdict
        print (d)
    else:
        print ("No %s to update" % (toBeUpdated))

updateInfo('Contact Info','Mobile Number','999 999 9999')
```

the result I get from this:

```
{'Name': 'A', 'Personal Details': {'Blood Group': 'O +ve', 'Age': '1', 'Sex': 'M'}, 'Contact Info': {'Phone  Number': '01234567', 'Mobile Number': '999 999 9999'}, 'Date of Birth': '01-01-95'}
```

Comment: what if there are 100's of values in csv file??

Comment: @anonymous by hundreds of values do you mean hundreds of line that are dicts of all the details of a customer or some person?

Comment: 100's of name,age,sex n other details of person in csv.

Comment: I want the key, value pair of mobile number and phone number to be updated inside another key called contact info. but Im looking for update methods  other than the two I have mentioned above